# How do I transition from one state to another without restarting it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

After transitioning from idle to forward jump I want to immediately go back to idle state but it replays the forward jump animation again.
I tried unchecking exit time but then the transition doesn't happen altogether.
How do I do this?

Here's the animation controller

[image: 1]

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to turn off "Loop Time" on your Animation Clip. [Loop Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyNzk.png)

Comment: loop time is already turned off